# How should I configure webpack build my node cli tool

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I have built a node cli tool, ideally I’d like to publish it on npm when it’s finished. How do I configure webpack to bundle the dependencies into one file that I can install globally from npm and then call as a command? Similar to create-react-app

Note that I have created the package already, defined the “bin”:{....} section of my package.json and it all works fine with npm link. I’m just not sure on the webpack setup that I need to be able to publish it and install from npm

Thanks

Comment: if bundling all dependencies into one file is not a hard requirement, then you should be fine without webpack for this process at all.

Comment: Would the package still work as a command line app? Any links to examples you could point me to?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack helps you to create build as single file with all your code also known as `bundle`. All dependencies will be added to the bundle. For CLI tool in contrast to fronted this doesn't work, because you will need to create build for every OS+Node.js version. **So you don't need webpack for CLI tool.**

Again, You shouldn't add dependencies to package archive, but webpack will do that. Don't forgot, during `preinstall`, `install`, `postinstall` steps npm does all required work as building C++ code and installing required dependencies for user's OS and Node.js version.

In my experience there was only one case when we had to store dependencies to build. It was node.js web-server for embedded device with small storage size. Our build had to be as small as possible. But this is not your case.

Maybe, you use `typescript` or `babel` for features, what node.js doesn't support. In this case, your code should be transpilted. Use `dist` folder as part of your package archive. Of course, you don't need store this folder at git.

Comment: Regarding your last point, how would you do to have only one obfuscated file in the `/dist` folder ? Using `outFile` in `tsconfig.json` does not work since you can't use `module: commonjs` with `outFile`.